# How to adjust a sub view based of the screen orientation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying a very basic app where there is a customised Menu Bar. The menu Bar is supposed to occupy 1/4th of the screen. And since this has to be calculated again when orientation changes, I am setting the menubar again everytime the orientation changes. But the problem is, when i initially open the app in portrait mode, the menubar is set right and even after the changing to landscape, it still is fine but when i swift from landsacpe to portarit, it for some reason does not do it right and the height of the menu bar is increased. Am I missing something ?

Below is my UIViewController

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController{

var metrics : [String : CGFloat] = [:]
let table = OptionsTable()
let menuBar = MenuBar()
var views : [UIView] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.getColorFromHex(hexCode: "1B9AF7")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

    setUpMenuBar()

}
private func setUpMenuBar(){
    views += [menuBar]
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    let bottomPaddingForMenuBar = view.frame.height - (view.frame.height/4)
    print("Padding \(bottomPaddingForMenuBar)")
    metrics.updateValue(bottomPaddingForMenuBar, forKey: "bottomPaddingFormenuBar")
    view.addConstraintWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: views, metrics: metrics)
    view.addConstraintWithFormat("V:|-0@750-[v0]-bottomPaddingFormenuBar@750-|", views: views, metrics: metrics)


}

override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
     setUpMenuBar()
    if fromInterfaceOrientation == .portrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == .portraitUpsideDown {
        print("Landscape")
    }else{
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Below is my `addConstarintWithFormat()` method

```
extension UIView{
func addConstraintWithFormat(_ format : String, views : [UIView], metrics : [String : CGFloat]) {

    var viewsDictionary = [String : UIView]()

    for(index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
    }
    print("duuh\(viewsDictionary["v0"]!)")
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary))

}
```

[image: Below is the image of the output and the console window]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why can't you add the constraint in storyboard?

Comment: Try Call setUpMenuBar  Method in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @KaushikMakwana this worked thank you! But why didn't mine work ?